# Wordpress register user only from a secret url

Tags: php, wordpress

I send a special url to my users who want to register on my wordpress website. So, I want to send them a url with a variable `invited=true` appended in it like: `http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register&invited=true` so that only those who have this url can register otherwise they are redirected to main page.

So if `invited=true` is in the url of registration page then go ahead, otherwise redirect to main website page. like:

```
if (!isset(GET('invited'))
  redirect $website_name;

if (GET('invited') != true)
  redirect $website_name;

//go ahead with the rest of the registration page code
```

where do I put this validation code? and what is the variable in WordPress for website name? so that I can put it in redirect instead of hard coding my website domain.

Please do not worry if someone else uses the url with variable, that is not an issue.

Comment: You can put the code in functions.php and use this to redirect to your site 'wp_redirect( home_url() )'

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a theme you "own", like a custom theme or a childtheme, you can hook this function to the login_head hook from your themes `functions.php`:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_head

If you don't "own" the theme, this will be overwritten the next time you update and in this case you will be looking at writing a plugin, which is a fair bit more complicated...:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: I am using theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/iconic-one/ and register plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/

Comment: Since you probably want to be able to update your theme, you should still look into creating a child theme.

The following tutorial shows how to easily create a child theme and better explains the Pros/Cons of a child theme:

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial


_Child themes allow you to make changes without affecting the original theme’s code, which makes it easy to update your parent theme without erasing your changes._

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your theme functions.php:

```
add_action('init','redirectUrl');

function redirectUrl(){
 if($_request['invited'] != true){
  $url = 'exampleurl.com';
  wp_redirect($url):
  }
}
```